# My search process gets slower through the multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, matrix

I´m new to this of parallel programming. I was trying to do a method for practicing but everytime the normal process takes less time than the parallel process in execute. Is something wrong with my implementation ?

```
    public class normalExecutor {

        public normalExecutor() {

        }

        public int[][] matriz = new int[3000][3000];

    public void search() {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int biggest = 0;
        matriz[800][800] = 9;

        for (int i = 0 ; i < 3000; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3000; j++) {
                if(matriz[i][j] == 9) {

                    long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    long elapsedTime = stopTime - startTime;

                    System.out.println("NOW normal "+ i + "|" + j + ": "  + elapsedTime);
                }
            }
        }


    }

}
```

And this was the try with the Parallel option

```
public class ParallelExecutor {

    final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
    final List<Future<?>> futures = new ArrayList<>();

    public int[][] matriz = new int[3000][3000];

    public ParallelExecutor() {

    }


    public void parallelSearch() {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        matriz[800][800] = 9;
        for (int i = 0 ; i < 3000; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3000; j++) {
                int x = i;
                int z = j;
                Future<?> future = executor.submit(() -> {
                    if(matriz[x][z] == 9) {
                        long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        long elapsedTime = stopTime - startTime;

                        System.out.println("NOW parallel "+ x + "|" + z+ ": "  + elapsedTime);
                    }
                });

                }
            }

    }
}
```

Even though sometimes the parallel one prints first the output comes always like this

```
   NOW parallel 800|800: 3089

    NOW normal 800|800: 21
```

Thanks

Comment: That's not a problem that parallelizes very well, you have a lot of overhead from creating objects etc. Multithreading isn't magic that makes everything faster.

Comment: Hint: you want us to spend our time to help you. So you please spend the 5 minutes to properly format/indent all of your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running a very simple and fast execution inside a separate thread 9 million times. Just the time it takes to create runnable to wrap your code, the `ExecutorService` to spend time waiting for available thread and running your code in it will be much greater.

The right approach is to split iteration of 3kx3k matrix into separate threads. For example give each thread 500 rows to process. This way you will have about 6 threads processing independent data in parallel.

I changed your code that shows how relatively fast parallel processing will be when you are dealing with execution that even takes 2 milliseconds for each row.

But I had to make two changes.

First I moved cell with 9 into the middle of matrix so that it will be much harder to find it quickly in normal search.

Second I added `Thread.sleep` to simulate long running execution in order to justify parallel processing.

```
final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
    final List<Future<?>> futures = new ArrayList<>();

    public int[][] matriz = new int[3000][3000];



    public void parallelSearch() {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        matriz[1580][1] = 9;

        executor.submit( () -> search( 0, 500, startTime) );
        executor.submit( () -> search( 500, 1000, startTime) );
        executor.submit( () -> search( 1000, 1500, startTime) );
        executor.submit( () -> search( 1500, 2000, startTime) );
        executor.submit( () -> search( 2000, 2500, startTime) );
        executor.submit( () -> search( 2500, 3000, startTime) );
    }

    public void search(int startRow, int endRow, long startTime){
        for (int i = startRow ; i < endRow; i++) {
            //add some execution time to justify parallel processing
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < 3000; j++) {
                int x = i;
                int z = j;

                if(matriz[x][z] == 9) {
                    long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    long elapsedTime = stopTime - startTime;

                    System.out.println("NOW parallel "+ x + "|" + z+ ": "  + elapsedTime);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void search() {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int biggest = 0;

        for (int i = 0 ; i < 3000; i++) {

            try {
                Thread.sleep(2);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < 3000; j++) {

                if( matriz[i][j] == 9 ) {

                    long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    long elapsedTime = stopTime - startTime;

                    System.out.println("NOW normal "+ i + "|" + j + ": "  + elapsedTime);
                }
            }
        }


    }
```

With the code above and using `Thread.sleep` you will have this result:

> NOW parallel 1580|1: 206
>
> NOW normal 1580|1: 3162

Without `Thread.sleep` (Threading overhead is much greater then the searching):

> NOW parallel 1580|1: 46
>
> NOW normal 1580|1: 9